# How to check for non-existent class? (getElementsByClassName)

Tags: javascript

```
arr = document.getElementsByClassName(type2);  // suppose type2 is not available in the dom - class = "some_class"
// check for empty
```

This snippet returns

[object HTMLCollection]

which has a length of 0.

Is this the best way to check for the class not existing when getElementsByClassName is used, i.e., just check for a length of 0?

Comment: Do you mean that the variable `type2` is undefined? Or did you mean to pass the string `'type2'`, and that there simply are no elements with that class? And why are you concerned that checking `.length === 0` is not optimal?

Comment: I take it that `!length` is more efficient then `length===0`?

Comment: One option perhaps worth testing is using `querySelector` instead of `getElementsByClassName`. The `querySelector` method returns the first result found, or `null` if none are found. `document.querySelector(".myclass") === null` Plus it gives you IE8 support, where `gEBCN` is unsupported.

Comment: ...and keep in mind that `gEBCN` returns a "live" Node List, which makes accessing the `.length` more expensive.

Comment: that has better compatibility as well.  IE8 supports it for those who care - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector

Comment: - in this case I need the live node list.

Comment: Then `gEBCN` is the way to go if you're actually using the resulting collection.

Comment: oh....just first element.

Comment: Yes, just the first. There's also `querySelectorAll`, which will return all matches, but it's still not a live list.

Comment: what do you mean by live list? ...that I can't manipulate the DOM this way?...read only.

Comment: A live list automatically updates when the DOM changes. So if you do `var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass");`, and if it returns 5 matches, then if you remove an element from the DOM that has the `"myclass"` class *(or if you just remove that class from the element)*, your `coll` list will update automatically to reflect the change to the DOM. The `querySelectorAll` method does not return a live list, so it's a snapshot of the matched elements, and does not reflect subsequent changes to the DOM.

Comment: if i update a property say `list[0].style.foo = "foo",` will it update the element ( supposing that it has not of course be removed ).

Comment: @HiroProtagonist: Yes, of course. It's the same element. I'm saying if you do `list[0].className = ""`, this will remove the class that was used to compile the list, and so that element will automatically be removed from the list if you used `getElementsByClassName`. If you used `querySelectorAll`, the element will not be removed from the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Check the `length` property of the returned collection.

---

Since `0` is falsy, you can do this:

```
var type2 = 'some_class';
var noElementHasType2Class = ! document.getElementsByClassName(type2).length;
```

Comment: I take it that `!length` is more efficient then `length===0`?

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - [They're basically the same](http://jsperf.com/class-collection-length-vs-equality).

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - He's asking *you* that question. Why do *you* think that it's not optimal?

Comment: you don't need to do a dom pull to run that test in the perf.....it's superfluous....off topic though

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - Why? There *could* have been a difference between accessing a NodeList's `length` property and accessing an array's. Just saying.

Comment: i think dom pulls take much more relative time then accessing the property....will reduce precision over all.  more off topic.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist - You're *so* right. Dunno what I was thinking. I updated [the JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/class-collection-length-vs-equality), but it produces the same results.

Comment: good info. to know...guess it is matter of style...i like the short way `!length`.